# Ios - Set default Text Color and FontSize

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I want to set a defualt textsize and color for all text across my ios app .
I'm looking for the IOS equivalent of the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources> 
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">        
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/default_textcolor</item>   
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>   
  </style>      
</resources>
```

Comment: Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged with [xamarin.forms](/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms), I assume you expect a `Xamarin.Forms` cross-platform solution.

`Xamarin.Forms` supports styles, and implicit styles. An implicit style is a style defined in a `ResourceDictionary` without an `x:Key` parameter. Implicit styles applies to all scoped xaml elements. So to apply an implicit style to all of your application, you should define it in your `App.xaml`

Every `Label` in your app will then, by default, have that Style applied.

If you want you implicit style to be applied on every `Label` AND every class inheriting from `Label` (not common with `Label`, but quite common if you style `ContentPage`), you can set `ApplyToDerivedTypes = "true"` to your `Style`.

Read more on Implicit Styles at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/implicit/